# @Published property inside an NSManagedObject doesn't trigger view updates

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I have a Core Data data model that I use in my app, and would like to add a property to that data model that I don't necessarily want to store, so instead of **@NSManaged** I made that property **@Published**.

```
 @Published var currentTime = "00:00"
```

And in the view instances I, of course, use an **@ObservedObject**

```
 @ObservedObject var timeItem: TimeItem
```

And in that view, I use a timer to update that value

```
.onReceive(Timer.publish(every: 0.015, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()) { time in
     timeItem.currentTime = timeItem.timeFinished.timeIntervalSince(Date()).editableStringMilliseconds()
 }
```

However, that doesn't trigger the view updates. I'm not sure if **NSManagedObject** is to blame, but if I replace that **timeItem.currentTime** value with a local @State one, everything works.

```
@State private var currentTime: String = "00:00"
```

Any ideas fellas?

Comment: Does your Object implement `ObservableObject` ?

Answer (score 2):

It's seems that there is a bug here or whatever it is. I had the same problem. To solve this issue you must trigger publisher manually:

```
 @Published var currentTime = "00:00" {
     willSet {
         objectWillChange.send()
     }
 }
```

At this moment you even don't need `@Published` wrapper.

To trigger update of `@NSManaged` properties you can override `willChangeValue` method.

```
override public func willChangeValue(forKey key: String) {  
    super.willChangeValue(forKey: key)  
    self.objectWillChange.send()  
}
```

I hope Apple will fix this strange behaviour as soon as possible.

Comment: It is strongly discouraged to override `willChangeValue` method here. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject#1653978